# Does Ubuntu support a VIA U4200 CPU?

Tags: hp, cpu, touchscreen, via

Does Ubuntu support this type of CPU?

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04, but I get only 640x840 video output.
Only Debian 7 gives me a full HD resolution.

It's a HP t510 mini PC. I want it for the parallel port on my CNC. It has great latency test( under 10000 ns) on Debian 7 wheezy, but I want to upgrade to a newer Linux, so that I can get the updates and use a touchscreen monitor.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_VIA_Eden_microprocessors#%22Eden_X2%22_(40_nm) shows it supports x64-86, SSE/2/3. MX, and x86 virtualization, so Ubuntu might run. I'd start with the lightest 'flavour' of Ubuntu, [Lubuntu 19.10](https://lubuntu.me), and if you have a different desktop preference, try that next.